# HTML Web Form conditional field query

Tags: html

I'm in the process of building a web form using HTML and I'm sure this is a simple query but I'm having trouble finding the answer.

By amending the following line:

```
<div id="A" style="display: none;">
```

I am only able to show all the questions or none.

What I want is when the user selects yes in the first question then div id = a will then appear and if he selects No it will skip to div id=b

Any ideas?

```
<body>
```

is there visitors to the property

```
<div id="referrals">
    <select id="QuestionOptions">
    <p>is there visitors to the property</p>
        <option value="A">Yes</option>
        <option value="B">No</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="referrals">
    <div id="A" style="display: none;">
        <div id="QuestionC">
            <p>Does he have liability cover</p>
        </div>
        <div id="QuestionD">
            <select id="QuestionOptionsD">
                <option value="G">Yes</option>
                <option value="H">No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="B" style="display: none;">
        <div id="QuestionE">
            <p>Does he have stock</p>
        </div>
        <div id="QuestionF">
            <select id="QuestionOptionsF">
                <option value="I">Yes</option>
                <option value="J">No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could do it with JavaScript/JQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with JQuery. You have to paste the following code at the end of your `<body>` tag

```
<body>
  ...
  ...YOUR HTML CODE GOES HERE
  ...
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script><!--THIS LOADS JQUERY FROM GOOGLE CDN-->
  <script> //this is your javascript function
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#QuestionOptions').change(function(){
        if ( $(this).val() == 'A'){
          $('#A').css('display','block');
          $('#B').css('display','none');
        }else{
          $('#B').css('display','block');
          $('#A').css('display','none');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not familar with JQuery how is this integrated into my original code?

Comment: @MattW I have edited my answer now. I recommend you learn javascript/jquery following at first some tutorial and then using the API documentation to see the proper use of the functions. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/) is a very nice tutorial where I used to learn when I started.